# Debian, virtualenv, IPython notebook and matplotlib inline plots

Tags: python, debian

I have been using IPython notebook on both OSX and Windows 7 for a while. Now I'm trying to create a minimal system for me to work on Debian 7 (Wheezy). I installed:

- LXDE
- Python2.7
- python-dev
- python-pip

then did a

```
apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib
```

Then did a

```
pip install pip --upgrade
pip install virtualenv
```

then in virtualenv, installed via pip:

- numpy
- pandas
- matplotlib
- ipython
- tornado

with this, I can run the IPython notebook, but when I plot anything, I only get the object (not the figure), as in

```
<matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0x42bf6d0>
```

I would really like to see the figures. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running %pylab inline in a notebook cell before executing the plot.

Comment: Interesting. I did start it with $ *ipython notebook pylab=inline*, just as I would in OSX or Windows. Isn't it supposed to work in Debian too?